# Declaração de matriz multidimensional

Tags: c#, array, .net, matriz

Estou tentando criar uma matriz multidimensional, mas não sei oque estou fazendo errado:

```
var players = new string[,]{ { { { "Armando", "P" }, { "Dave", "S" } }, { { "Richard", "R" }, { "Michael", "S" } } }, { { { "Allen", "S" }, { "Omer", "P" } }, { { "David E.", "R" }, { "Richard X.", "P" } } } };
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

[image: Como deve sair no final quando a matriz já está montada]

Quero criar um objeto como esse abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quantas dimensões deve ter a matriz?

Comment: @Maniero coloquei um exemplo do que eu gostaria de criar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não parece fazer sentido, mas está montando um *array* de 4 dimensões, então tem que declarar desta forma. Também fiz pra duas (a quantidade declarada no código), mas pelo resultado apresentado parece querer 4 mesmo, ainda que eu acho que no máximo 3 resolveria, por isso fiz para essa quantidade também.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var players = new string[,,,] { { { { "Armando", "P" }, { "Dave", "S" } }, { { "Richard", "R" }, { "Michael", "S" } } }, { { { "Allen", "S" }, { "Omer", "P" } }, { { "David E.", "R" }, { "Richard X.", "P" } } } };
        var players3 = new string[,,] { { { "Armando", "P" }, { "Dave", "S" } }, { { "Richard", "R" }, { "Michael", "S" } }, { { "Allen", "S" }, { "Omer", "P" } }, { { "David E.", "R" }, { "Richard X.", "P" } } };
        var players2 = new string[,] { { "Armando", "P" }, { "Dave", "S" }, { "Richard", "R" }, { "Michael", "S" }, { "Allen", "S" }, { "Omer", "P" }, { "David E.", "R" }, { "Richard X.", "P" } };
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5lGlV1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ArKPy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/MultipleDimention.cs).